# Decimal value rounded up in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Everytime I execute UPDATE function with decimal values it captures rounded off integer values. Anyone knows what’s the datatype to use? I tried money and float still I’m getting rounded off value.

Here’s my .vb code

```
cmd.CommandText=“UPDATE [dbo].[transaction] SET Price=@Price WHERE ID=@ID”
cmd.Parameters.Add(“@Price”,SqlDbType,Decimal,18,2).Values=Textbox1.text
cmd.Parameters.Add(“@ID”,SqlDbType,Int).Values=Textbox2.text

SQL Server Datatype
ID(PK,Int,not null)
Price(decimal(18,2),null)

Input: 25.75
Result: 25
Desired Result: 25.75
```

Comment: You should copy / paste your code here, don't *rewrite* it -- `Textbox1.text` is a string, not a decimal value. Use `Decimal.TryParse()` to generate an actual Decimal value from it

Comment: Hi @Jimi same thing…the fact that I already specified the SqlDbType, it should be working even .text is considered as string…

Comment: Hi @Jimi, sorry I came to realize that I applied it with regex, anything matches “[\,|\.[0-9].*$” will be replaced by empty(“”) so that it will become whole number…Thank you though. Sorry for that. :)

Comment: Regex? Don't regex anything, as mentioned, just use `decimal.TryParse()` (since this appears to be User input, hence you need to validate it) to generate a decimal value and pass this value to the Parameter. The scale is already set in the Column's definition, that's all you need

Comment: Hi Jimi, I am using it now as you advised. My quantity, discount, and price modifications are in the same condition I used the same textbox, since quantity should be in integer only I used regex to remove decimals in case the user inputs not a whole number, but I forgot to remove from price and discount that’s why it captures all integers only…Thank you though.

Comment: You can use `Decimal.Truncate()` for that. Not sure what *I used the same textbox* means, you have two TextBox controls in your questions

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) - it would have pointed out that there is no overload of [`.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) which takes (String, SqlDbType, Integer, Integer).

You could use something like:

```
Dim dv = Decimal.Parse(Textbox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {
                   .ParameterName = "@Price",
                   .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal,
                   .Precision = 18,
                   .Scale = 2,
                   .Value = dv})
```

(You should also set Option Strict On as the default for new VB projects.)